# what is the equivalent of sqldbtype.structured for OLEDBParameter OLEDBtype?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, oledbcommand, table-valued-parameters

i want to pass a table valued parameter through a OledbParameter to OledbCommand.In SqlParameter there is a DBtype called Structured where you can assign a TVP to the SQlParameter
No clue how to pass TVP to OledbParameter

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you got the answer pavan?

Comment: @Maddy  yes,the answer is you can't,with OLEDBParameter